# Deleting UITableViewCell raises exception

Tags: ios, objective-c, exception, uitableview

I am trying to delete a UITableViewCell like this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
{
    [self._tableViewItems beginUpdates];
    [self._tableViewItems deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
    [self._tableViewItems endUpdates];

    [[AppDelegate appDelegate].managedObjectContext deleteObject:[_arraySortedItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    NSError *error = nil;
    [[AppDelegate appDelegate].managedObjectContext save:&error];
}

[self getItems];

}
```

Here is getItems:

```
-(void)getItems
{
_arrayAllItems = NULL;
_arrayAllItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:[[AppDelegate appDelegate]getItems]];


_arraySortedItems = NULL;
_arraySortedItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:_arrayAllItems];

[_tableViewItems reloadData];
[_tableViewItems setNeedsLayout];
```

}

But this code fails at [self._tableViewItems endUpdates]; with this exception:

```
Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], /SourceCache/UIKit/UIKit-2903.23/UITableView.m:1330
```

Searched the web, but no solution could help me.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

You can simply create a master-detail project to get the demo reference of this. It is already available there. or you can try this.

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
// Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
return YES;
}

if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
    [_objects removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
}
```

Please let me know if it works.

Comment: Sry, I get the same error, now at this line:[tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

Comment: Ok. Did you take reference from the master detail project that I mentioned. If not, please create a new project and instead of single view application,choose master-detail. Its a nice demo which you can refer for the delete functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Try flipping this around - I think you need to delete the object before deleting the row. Otherwise the number of cells doesn't match what the UITableView thinks it should be after deleting the row.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
{

    [[AppDelegate appDelegate].managedObjectContext deleteObject:[_arraySortedItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    NSError *error = nil;
    [[AppDelegate appDelegate].managedObjectContext save:&error];

    [self._tableViewItems beginUpdates];
    [self._tableViewItems deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
    [self._tableViewItems endUpdates];


}
```